# How to have project print and to print certain items from webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I want to do is to be able to print out a web page. I believe I am looking for a print preview page but I am not sure on how to do this. I would only like to print out certain information of the current page.

Here is my Controller

```
using NavisionStore.Domain.Abstract;
using NavisionStore.Domain.Entities;
using NavisionStore.WebUI.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace NavisionStore.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class PrintController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository repository;

        public PrintController(IProductRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }

        public ViewResult Index(string returnUrl)
        {
            return View(new PrintIndexViewModel
            {
                Print = GetPrint(),
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl
            });
        }
         public RedirectToRouteResult AddtoPrint(int id, string returnUrl)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

            if (product != null)
            {
                GetPrint().AddItem(product, 1);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }

        public RedirectToRouteResult RemoveFromPrint(int id, string returnUrl)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

            if (product != null)
            {
                GetPrint().RemoveLine(product);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }

        private Print GetPrint()
        {
            Print print = (Print)Session["Print"];
            if (print == null)
            {
                print = new Print();
                Session["Print"] = print;
            }
            return print;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my  view model class

```
using NavisionStore.Domain.Entities;

namespace NavisionStore.WebUI.Models
{
    public class PrintIndexViewModel
    {
        public Print Print { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my index view model

```
@model NavisionStore.WebUI.Models.PrintIndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Bag Labels: Your Print";
}

<h2>Caplugs West</h2>
<table width="90%" align="center">
    <thead><tr>
        <th align="center">PN:</th>
        <th align="center">QTY:</th>
        <th align="center">B#</th>
           </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var line in Model.Print.Lines) {
            <tr>
                <td align="center">@line.Product.PartName</td>
                <td align="center">@line.Product.Quantity</td>
                <td align="center">@line.Product.BagNumber</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <p align="center" class="actionButtons">
        <a href="@Model.ReturnUrl">Continue shopping</a>
    </p>
```

Here is my default layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
   <div id="header">
       <div class="title">Bag Labels</div>
   </div>
    <div id="categories">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); }
    </div>
    <div id="content">
         @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screen shot of how it currently lays out.

[image: Screenshot]

I want to print out everything in white from the lin over such as the "caplus west" "pn" "qty" and "b#"

Here is my Site.css

```
body {
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: #232323;
    background-color: #fff;
}

header, footer, nav, section {
    display: block;
}


/* Styles for basic forms
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
}

legend {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

textarea {
    min-height: 75px;
}

.editor-label {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

.editor-field {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}


/* Styles for validation helpers
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
.field-validation-error {
    color: #f00;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    background-color: #fee;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f00;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}

BODY { font-family: Cambria, Georgia, "Times New Roman"; margin: 0; }
DIV#header DIV.title, DIV.item H3, DIV.item H4, DIV.pager A {
    font: bold 1em "Arial Narrow", "Franklin Gothic Medium", Arial;
}

DIV#header {
    background-color: #444;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #111;
    color: white;
}
DIV#header DIV.title {
        font-size: 2em;
        padding: .6em;
}
DIV#content {
    border-left: 2px solid gray;
    margin-left: 9em;
    padding: 1em;
}
DIV#categories {
    float: left;
    width: 8em;
    padding: .3em;
}

DIV.item {
    border-top: 1px dotted gray;
    padding-top: .7em;
    margin-bottom: .7em;
}
    DIV.item:first-child {
        border-top: none;
        padding-top: 0;
}
    DIV.item H3 {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        margin: 0 0 .25em 0;
}
    DIV.item H4 {
        font-size: 1.1em;
        margin: .4em 0 0 0;
}

DIV.pager {
    text-align: right;
    border-top: 2px solid silver;
    padding: .5em 0 0 0;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
DIV.pager A {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 .4em 0 .4em;
}
    DIV.pager A:hover {
        background-color: silver;
    }
    DIV.pager A.selected {
        background-color: #353535;
        color: white;
    }

DIV#categories A {
    font: bold 1.1em "Arial Narrow","Franklin Gothic Medium",Arial;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .6em;
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}
    DIV#categories A.selected {
        background-color: #666;
        color: white;
    }
    DIV#categories A.hover {
        background-color: #CCC;
    }
    DIV#categories A.selected:hover {
        background-color: #666;
    }

FORM {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
DIV.item FORM {
    float: right;
}
DIV.item INPUT {
    color: white;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

H2 {
    margin-top: 0.3em;
}
.actionButtons A, INPUT.actionButtons {
    font: .8em Arial;
    color: white;
    margin: .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .15em 1.5em .2em 1.5em;
    background-color: #353535;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
@media print {
    .noprint {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media print {
    #header, #categories, .actionButtons {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to control what happens when your page is printed

for example in you css file if you do

```
@media print {
  .noprint { display: none; }
}
```

Then you can do

```
@model NavisionStore.WebUI.Models.PrintIndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Bag Labels: Your Print";
}

<h2>Caplugs West</h2>
<table width="90%" align="center">
<thead><tr>
    <th align="center">PN:</th>
    <th align="center">QTY:</th>
    <th align="center">B#</th>
       </tr></thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach(var line in Model.Print.Lines) {
        <tr>
            <td align="center">@line.Product.PartName</td>
            <td align="center">@line.Product.Quantity</td>
            <td align="center">@line.Product.BagNumber</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
<p align="center" class="actionButtons noprint">
    <a href="@Model.ReturnUrl">Continue shopping</a>
</p>
```

And the buttons won't appear when you print.

** UPDATE2 **

Put the following at the end of Site.css

```
@media print {
  #header, #categories, .actionButtons {
      display: none;
  }

  DIV#content {
      border-left: 0;
      margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

I've also created a JS fiddle to show it working http://jsfiddle.net/Hg79x/1/

Now when you view the page you will get the full page, but your print (or browser print preview dialog)  will only contain the content.

You could also add some formatting to the `body` and `html` inside the `@media print` section to format the page layout further (e.g. set the width)

Comment: When I did this nothing happens I am able to print the page but I would only like to print certain parts of the webpage not the entire page. Since I do not have a 10 reputation I cannot add a screen shot of my webpage so I can better explain myself. I guess I need to add a print preview screen so that I can grab only certain information from the webpage then print the print preview page?

Comment: @MikeMacko  This css will allow your print version of the page to exclude certain data.  So any element you tag with a class of `noprint` will appear on screen but will be excluded when you print it

Comment: @MikeMacko really need a screen shot, can you not provide a pastebin link?

Comment: I am not seeing an option on pastebin for me to attach a file or show a picture

Comment: I am not sure how to use pastbaord I clicked and dragged my screen shot onto it, and then what how to do upload the photo there is no option

Comment: Could I maybe email it to you?

Comment: @MikeMacko When you drag the image onto it you then click upload.  This gives you url you can share. I'd rather not give out an email address on a public forum.

Comment: Ahh, got it. the upload button was not there before. Her is the link http://pbrd.co/19HaVQr    I want to print out everything in white from the lin over such as the "caplus west" "pn" "qty" and "b#"

Comment: @MikeMacko From the looks of the screen shot the areas you don't want to see are not in your view.  These appear to be in your default layout?  Can you provide your default layout?

Comment: I have just added my default layout

Comment: @MikeMacko See the updated answer, specifically the part after update

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much it looks great, everything that I need printed is printing and everything I don't want to print is now printing. But, is there anyway to not print the vertical line next to the "caplugs west" and "home". And it also printing out a header pf "bag leabels:your print and page 1 of 1" and the fotter is the website and the date. Any way to remove those from the print?

Comment: @MikeMacko I believe the vertical line is part of the css somewhere, possibly on the div with an id of content.  The page 1 of 1 etc is part of internet explorer can you can turn it off in your print settings.  There are tricks with `@page { size: auto; margin 0; }` inside the `@media print` tag but these don't always work.

Comment: I have added my Site.css. When I add content to the "@media print" it deletes everything in the print not just the line. Any ideas?

Comment: @MikeMacko Yes you need to just change the border and margin settings see my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry that I am just getting back to this now. It worked! thank your for all your help I really appreciate it. Thank you